# ODE with Laplace transform: the jump of $\dot y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity, laplace-transform

I solved this eq. using the Laplace Transform:

$\ddot y+4\dot y+13 y=\delta(t-2\pi)-\delta(t-7\pi)$

The sol. is:

$y(t)=\frac{1}{3} e^{2 t} (-e^{14 \pi} \theta(t-7\pi) sin(3 t)+e^{4 \pi} \theta(t-2 \pi) sin(3 t)+2 sin(3 t)+3 cos(3 t))$

or
$y(t)=\begin{cases}
  e^{-2t}\cos {3t}+\frac{2}{3}e^{-2t}\sin{3t} \quad \mbox{if} \quad t<2\pi\\
  e^{-2t}\cos {3t}+(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}e^{4\pi})e^{-2t}\sin{3t}\quad \mbox{if} \quad2\pi<t<7\pi \\
  e^{-2t}\cos {3t}+(\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}e^{4\pi}+\frac{1}{3}e^{14\pi})e^{-2t}\sin{3t}\quad \mbox{if} \quad t>7\pi
 \end{cases}$

Now I am being asked what is the "jump" in $\dot y(t)$ at $t=2\pi$ and $t=7\pi$.
Could any one explain me a way to answer it?
I know how to find the difference in $\dot y$ at a certain point but not by what extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're asking for

$$\lim_{t \to 2 \pi^+} y'(t) - \lim_{t \to 2 \pi^-} y'(t)$$

and the same at $7 \pi$. However, you don't need the solution to calculate these, all you need to assume is that $y(t)$ and $y'(t)$ are bounded (or even just integrable). Rewrite the equation

$$y''(t) = -4y'(t) - 13y(t) + \delta(t-2\pi)-\delta(t-7\pi)$$

and integrate both sides around $2 \pi$:

$$\int_{2 \pi - c}^{2 \pi + c} y''(t) dt = \int_{2 \pi - c}^{2 \pi + c} -4y'(t) - 13y(t) + \delta(t-2\pi)-\delta(t-7\pi) dt$$

By the FTC, the left hand side is $y'(2 \pi+c)-y'(2 \pi-c)$, so the jump at $2 \pi$ will be the limit as $c \to 0$ of the right hand side. In other words

$$\lim_{c \to 0} y'(2 \pi + c)-y'(2 \pi - c) = \lim_{c \to 0} \int_{2 \pi - c}^{2 \pi + c} -4y'(t) - 13y(t) + \delta(t-2 \pi) - \delta(t - 7 \pi) dt$$

Using that $y'$ and $y$ are integrable along with properties of the delta function we get

$$\lim_{c \to 0} y'(2 \pi + c)-y'(2 \pi - c) = 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 1.$$

By looking at the term that survived, you can see the pattern: if the equation is linear, its order is $n$, and the right side contains $a \delta(t-b)$, then the $(n-1)$th derivative of the solution will have a jump of size $a$ at $b$.