# the jump in $\ddot y$, Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Given the following IVP:

$$\ddot y+4y=\cos t-\cos t \cdot  \theta(t-2\pi), y(0)=0, \dot y(0)=1$$
Check that $y(t)$ is continuous at $t=2\pi$.

Find the jump in $\ddot y(t)$ at $t=2\pi$ i.e find $\lim _{t\to2\pi^+}\ddot y(t)-\lim _{t\to2\pi^-}\ddot y(t)$.

I know how to get the answer for the first one by using the solution. Is there another way to do it?

And I need some explanation for the "jump". I asked a quite similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/896452/ode-with-laplace-transform-the-jump-of-dot-y) to this a few days ago but I don't to use the solution I've been given for finding the jump in $y\ddot (t)$.
Thank you very much!

Comment: If $y$ is continuous, then $y''(t) = \cos(t) - 4y(t)$ is also continuous. What does this tell us about the oscillation and thus jump of $y''$?

Comment: Is your ODE look like this: $\ddot y+4y=\cos t-\cos t \cdot  \theta(t-2\pi)$.  I deleted the extra "," after $\cos t$.

Comment: @ mike: I edited my equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\ddot y+4y=\cos t-\cos t \cdot  \theta(t-2\pi)$$

Because $y(t)$ is continuous at $t=2\pi$, we have

$$\lim _{t\to2\pi^+}\ddot y(t)-\lim _{t\to2\pi^-}\ddot y(t)=\lim _{c\to 0}\left(\ddot y(2\pi+c)-\ddot y(2\pi-c)\right)$$
$$=-\cos (2\pi) \cdot  \lim _{c\to 0}(\theta(c)-\theta(-c))=-1 \cdot (1-0)=-1$$

Comment: mike, thank you for your reply. Let's equate $\ddot y(t)$: $$\ddot y(t)=-4y+\cos t -\cos t \cdot \theta(t-2\pi)$$. So that we get the 2 limits like this: $$\cos(2\pi+c)-4y(2\pi+c)-\cos(2\pi+c)\cdot \theta(\2pi+c-2\pi)-[cos(2\pi-c)-4y(2\pi-c)+\cos(2\pi-c)\cdot \theta(2\pi-c-2\pi)]$$. Now what do I know about the term $$y(2\pi-c)$$?

Comment: $\lim_{c\to 0}\left(-y(2\pi+c)+y(2\pi-c)\right)=\left(-y(2\pi)+y(2\pi)\right)=0$ because $y(t)$ is continuous near $t=2\pi$

Comment: I got you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: mike, another question: What if I had been given a $\dot y $ term in the LHS? Say the equation was in the form of $$\ddot y=-p(t)\cdot \dot y -q(t)\cdot y(t)+g(t).$$ I mean, I want to the calc the jump in $\ddot y$ at $t=a$ and I finally get this one to calculate: $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \dot y (a+\varepsilon)-\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \dot y (a-\varepsilon)$$ What do I know about $\dot y$?

Comment: Generally speaking if $p(t),q(t),g(t)$ are continuous, then there is no jump in $\dot y(t),\ddot y(t)$. If $p(t)$ is discontinuous, then $\ddot y(t)$ has jump and $\dot y(t)$ is smooth. So the jump is equal to $(-p(a+0)+p(a-0))f'(a)$